# UPDATE row when changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script that must update some fields in a big table, many times.
In the main loop, I do queries like this:

```
UPDATE books SET title='ABC' WHERE code=123
```

I know that in more than 99.9% of the cases, the title will not be changed by the query, because it was already set to 'ABC'.
I would like to make this loop as efficient as possible.
Instead, I could do:

```
SELECT title FROM books WHERE code=123
```

then, compare the result with my string, and only when it is different perform the UPDATE.
When the title changes, I would run one more query, but this is negligible because almost never the value needs to be changed.

My question is: would this be more efficient? In other words, is an UPDATE that cause no changes to a field more efficient than a SELECT that retrieves the same field?

Comment: Can't you use `UPDATE books SET title='ABC' WHERE code=123 AND title!='ABC'`?
On the efficiency side, looping through the results of a SELECT will be less efficient than updating the record, because most of the time spent by the system will be locating the record you want to update, not updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading is generally more performant because it can be done in a non-blocking way by utilizing `(NOLOCK)` or by setting the transaction level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`

Updates are a blocking statement and will lock the row for the duration of the transaction even though the update field is not being changed.